# JSON String - more than two parameters - receiving null at servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, servlets

I am passing two JSON objects from jQuery - ajax call to servlet using JSON Stringify. But I am getting null. If I pass one Object I am getting expected data but I'm not able to receive two objects. Please help me to find my mistake.

```js
$.ajax({
    url : 'insertserv1',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"test1" :masterdata,"test2" :InspTableArray}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    success : function(data) {
        alert('Hi');
    }
});
```

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));       

if (br != null) {
    json = br.readLine();
}

System.out.println(json); // getting expected data as {"test1":{"grn":"55555","pono":"888888","row":1},"test2":["Type/,"As ","ok","ok","ok","ok","ok"]}

try {
   JSONObject rawdata = new JSONObject(json);
   JSONObject datat1 = rawdata.getJSONObject("test1");
   JSONObject datat2 = rawdata.getJSONObject("test2");

   System.out.println(datat1); // return nulls
   System.out.println(datat2); // return nulls
```

Comment: `I am passing two JSON object from jquery` - no, you're passing a JSON string of an object with two top level properties, test1 and test2

Comment: sorry. could u please tell me what s the issue with above code

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know java well enough ... your javascript code looks fine ... your java code is alien to me

Comment: Have you looked at what `rawdata` actually contains?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian no . its not returing any

Answer (score 0):

The JSON that is being sent in the `InspTableArray` is invalid so when you try and parse it in Java it breaks:

```
{"test1":{"grn":"55555","pono":"888888","row":1},"test2":["Type/,"As ","ok","ok","ok","ok","ok"]}
// Problem is this character here    --------------------------^
// which breaks the JSON Array of strings

// The value should be "Type" instead of "Type/
// and is likely causing a SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 66
```

`test2` seems to be an array of strings, apart from the first element which isn't a String and causes the rest of the Array to break and should be:

```
"test2":["Type","As ","ok","ok","ok","ok","ok"]
//            ^------ forward slash replaced with closing double-quotation mark
```

Comment: okie. So u meant, we cant give any special characters, including spaces?

Comment: JSON is a variation of JavaScript object notation which is a collection of name/value pairs. [Check out the JSON docs for the full spec](http://www.json.org)

Comment: but. now my string is like {"test2":["TypeRating","AsperPO","ok","ok","ok","ok","ok"]}, but now also i am not able to get any data

Comment: So `System.out.println(datat2);` still outputs null